# Force open of main activity

Tags: android, main-activity

I have an android app chat. It has to be secure so I want to force my app to open always at Main Activity. This doesn't happen when I click the history of launcher, it opens the activity shown on launcher history not the main activity. How can I force it open the Main Activity always?

> android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"

I have this on Manifest but doesn't work.

Comment: Please show your code

Answer (score 0):

that seems right and it should work but this option is  a bit buggy when you build the app directly to the device, please try to install the apk manually

Answer (score 0):

I offer you another way.

Look at the [Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html), namely on :

- [onActivityPaused](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html#onActivityPaused(android.app.Activity))
- [onActivityResumed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html#onActivityResumed(android.app.Activity))
- [onActivityCreated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html#onActivityCreated(android.app.Activity,%20android.os.Bundle))

When application was closed with HOME button or launch from recent task, you may have determine a `boolean` value that can be saved in [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

```
boolean isSecure = false;
```

> When activity paused - isSecure **->** true **->** save into sp.
>   When activity resumed\paused - read from sp **->** `isSecure = sp.getBoolean(...,false);`